# How do you gain research?

Tags: succubox

I have several things in the shop that require research to purchase and I have a counter under my finances for it, but I haven't found a way to increase it. How do I gain research?

Edit: I seem to have received one research, but I'm not sure what caused it. Does it accrue over time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to murgatroid99 for explaining it to me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40751778#40751778), you receive research by clicking work while having no paperwork to do.